MAUI Community Toolkit Popup for Android moves the content unexpected
In my NET8 MAUI application, I want to display a Popup message when the application is loading data. For this reason, I created this page
<toolkit:Popup
    x:Class="LanguageInUse.Views.Popups.LoadingPopup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:popups="clr-namespace:LanguageInUse.Views.Popups"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit">

    <toolkit:Popup.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type popups:LoadingPopup}">
            <Setter Property="Size" Value="300,300" />
            <Setter Property="Color" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup" Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </toolkit:Popup.Resources>

    <StackLayout
        Margin="30"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        WidthRequest="350">
        <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <ActivityIndicator
                Margin="25"
                IsRunning="True"
                Color="{StaticResource Gray900}" />
            <Label
                x:Name="labelLoading"
                Style="{StaticResource labelLoading}"
                Text="Loading..." />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</toolkit:Popup>

The style is a static resource and is this one
<Style x:Key="labelLoading" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource Gray900}}" />
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
    <Setter Property="LineBreakMode" Value="WordWrap" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,15,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>

The implementation for Windows and iOS is OK but in Android there is something annoying. The label in the body starts to be placed in the right position but after a few seconds, it has moved on the right. Here the gif with the issue

Do you know where the issue is?

Have you tried to change the value of widthReques ,margin to adjust the Label text location?
